# Refactor component with else if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My question is how to refactor my code, first of all, I have an `item.status` which could be "active", "non_active" and "pending", when this `item.status` is "active" I render a button, when is "inactive" I render another button but when this item is "pending" I do render both buttons, so I appreciate the help.

Here's my code:

```
const renderAcceptActions = (item, onClickActivate, onClickDeactivate) => {
    if (item.status == "non_active") {
      return (
        <td>
          {onClickActivate && (
            <CButton
              color="primary"
              variant="outline"
              size="sm"
              className="mr-2"
              onClick={() => onClickActivate(item)}
            >
              Ativar
            </CButton>
          )}
        </td>
      );
    } else if (item.status == "active") {
      return (
        <td>
          {onClickDeactivate && (
            <CButton
              color="danger"
              variant="outline"
              size="sm"
              onClick={() => onClickDeactivate(item)}
            >
              Desativar
            </CButton>
          )}
        </td>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <td>
          {onClickActivate && (
            <CButton
              color="primary"
              variant="outline"
              size="sm"
              className="mr-2"
              onClick={() => onClickActivate(item)}
            >
              Ativar
            </CButton>
          )}
          {onClickDeactivate && (
            <CButton
              color="danger"
              variant="outline"
              size="sm"
              onClick={() => onClickDeactivate(item)}
            >
              Desativar
            </CButton>
          )}
        </td>
      );
    }
  };
```

Comment: Kind of a FooBar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define two variables like below

```
const renderFirstButton = item.status === 'active' || item.status === 'pending';
const renderSecondButton = item.status === 'inactive' || item.status === 'pending';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (item.status == "non_active" || item.status == "pending"){render first button}
if (item.status == "active" || item.status == "pending"){render second button}
```

Comment: Please add some supporting information with your answer

Comment: Thanks for the help!